# Nested http request in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, frontend

I'm beginner in Angular so I faced a challenge. How to interact with nested http request in Angular using RxJS ?

```
.pipe(
    map((res): Collection => ({
            id: res.id,
            name: res.name,
            description: res.description,
            tracks: res.tracks.items.map(track => this.trackService.fetchTrack(track.id)) //?
        }) 
    ),
)
```

Comment: You may find [inspiration here](https://medium.com/better-programming/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `switchMap` to map from outer observable to inner. And seeing that you have multiple HTTP calls from an array, you could use `forkJoin` to trigger them in parallel.

Try the following

```js
outerObservable().pipe(
  switchMap((res): Collection => {
    forkJoin(res.tracks.items.map(track => this.trackService.fetchTrack(track.id))).pipe(
      map(tracks => ({
        id: res.id,
        name: res.name,
        description: res.description,
        tracks: tracks
      }))
    )
  })
).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked for me, but the one thing I had to do is to replace (res: Collection) by (res): Collection

Comment: Not sure why `(res: Collection)` wouldn't work but nevertheless I've updated the answer to reflect your change.